# Suppose the probability density of random variable X is f(x), $-\infty< x<\infty$ what is the probability density of $Y=X^3$?

Tags: probability

I see a question in my math book.

> Suppose the probability density of random variable X is $f(x)$, $-\infty< x<\infty$ what is the probability density of $Y=X^3$?

The answer I calculated is $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{3}y^{(-2/3)}f(y^{1/3}),\quad -\infty< y<\infty.$

The processes of that is

$$F_Y(y)=P\{Y\le y\}=P\{X^3\le y\}=P\{X\le y^{1/3}\}=F_X(y^{1/3})$$

Find the derivative on both sides for $y$

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(y^{1/3})\frac{1}{3}y^{-2/3}$$
$y$ could be any reals, so $-\infty< y<\infty.$

But the answer in the math book is $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{3}y^{(-2/3)}f(y^{1/3}),\quad y\ne0.$

Why does $y\ne0$ in the answer?

Comment: The expression for $f_Y(y)$ is not defined for $y=0$, but you can assign any value for $f_Y(0)$. That is immeterial. BTW don't write $-\infty \le x \le \infty$ etc. $\pm \infty$ are not real numbers.

Comment: @geetha290krm 1. Why did you say that $f_Y(y)$ is not defined for $y=0$? When $y=0$, what will happen? 2. Why did you say that $\pm\infty$ are not real numbers? Could it still be an imaginary number?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to say $-\infty \leq x\leq \infty$, because it implies that $x$ could be equal to $\pm \infty$. It's more appropriate to write either $-\infty <x<\infty$, $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$, or even just $x\in\mathbb{R}$.